# react-boostrap and react-router causing full page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am just trying to get `React-Boostrap` and `React-Router` up and running together. I used **Create React App** to create a simple shell.

This is my code, which does actual work nicely with `React Router`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps, useHistory } from 'react-router';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    useParams,
    BrowserRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {
    Nav,
    Navbar
} from "react-bootstrap";

function Navigation() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter >
            <div>
                <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="mr-auto">
                            <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/users/1">/users/1</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/users/2">/users/2</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/users2/1">/users2/1</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>

                {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
                    renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/about">
                        <About />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/users/:id" render={() => <Users />}/>
                    <Route path="/users2/:id" component={Users2} />
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter >
    );
}

class AppRouterBootstrap extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="App">
                <Navigation />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AppRouterBootstrap;

function Home() {
    return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
    return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
    // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
    // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
    let { id } = useParams();
    let history = useHistory();

    const handleClick = () => {
        history.push("/home");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Go home</button>
        </div>
    );
}

class Users2 extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello {(this.props.match.params as any).id}!</h1 >
                <button
                    type='button'
                    onClick={() => { this.props.history.push('/users/1') }} >
                    Go to users/1
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Which looks like this when rendered. Which looks ok, and actually works (on a navigation, and parameters etc etc point of view just fine)

[image]

However what I am noticing is that whenever I click on one of the `React-Boostrap nav` links, there is a **FULL network reload occurring**, if I monitor the Network tab. If I do not use `React-Boostrap nav`, but instead use a simple `react-router` and some `Link` from  react-router. this full reload is not occurring. It only seems to happen when using `React-Boostrap` nav links

Does anyone know if this is normal, should `React-Boostrap nav` when used with React-Router be doing this. I guess its possible since its not using the inbuilt `React-Router Link` classes, but rather its own Nav based items.

Anyone have any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `Nav.Link` will refresh the pages by default (same functionality as a href).

To avoid this behavior, instead of `href`, you can pass the props `as` and `to` (more details [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props)).

For example:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// ...

<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about">About</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: Sunil shortly after I posted this, I did try without using the react boostrap Nav, and just used Link which worked without reload. So thanks for joining both those dots together for me. This works as expected now. Thanks

Comment: This should be the dafault behaviour.

Comment: I had to use <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/">

Comment: @jeevan when I use as={NavLink}, it does a full page reload again.

Comment: good, it helped me. thanks